# My web app works only with META-INF instead of WEB-INF including beans.xml. Why?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, wildfly-8, meta-inf

I am working on examples of Dependency Injection in java, and most of the documents highlights that I have to put an empty `beans.xml` in

- META-INF if it is a jar application
- WEB-INF if it is a web application

So, I use war type packaging but, my application only works if I put `beans.xml` in META-INF folder. I am confused a little bit about why it is working with that way ? I deploy my war file in JBOSS/WildFly container.

Here is my simple [pom.xml](http://pastebin.com/dCvf6Emw)

beans.xml lies in `src/main/resources/META-INF`

Also here you can see which annotations I only used for injecting the beans.

***AutoService.java***

```
public interface AutoService {
    void getService();
}
```

***BMWAutoService.java***

```
@Named("bmwAutoService")
public class BMWAutoService implements AutoService{

    @Override
    public void getService() {
        System.out.println("You chose BMW auto service");
    }
}
```

***AutoServiceCaller.java***

```
@Named
public class AutoServiceCallerImp implements AutoServiceCaller{

    private AutoService bmwAutoService;

    @Inject
    public AutoServiceCallerImp(@Named("bmwAutoService") AutoService bmwAutoService) {

        this.bmwAutoService = bmwAutoService;
    }

    @Override
    public void callAutoService() {
        // get bmw's auto service
        bmwAutoService.getService();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends where you are using annotations. If you have EJB beans in your web module and are using injections in these beans, then you will need to have `beans.xml` in the `META-INF` as it would be in case of pure ejb module. If you are using CDI injections in web components (servlets, filters, JSF beans) then you would have to have it in `WEB-INF`. You may also need them in both places (if used from both kind of components).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have only used `@Named` and `@Inject` annotations to inject the beans. So, does it mean that I am using EJB beans ? And I added very simple example of code I used

Comment: @quartaela No, it looks like you are using only web beans. So after packaging your beans.xml should be in `WEB-INF`. Try to put your beans.xml into `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF` folder, not `src/main/resources/META-INF`.

Comment: That works! Can you tell me difference between `src\main\webapp` and `src\main\resources` ? I was trying to put `WEB-INF` in resources folder as I do for `META-INF`

Comment: @quartaela This is how [Maven archetype](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-archetypes.html) works. The `resources` folder is a root folder for resources :) and files placed there are copied to the compiled classes folder, so `WEB-INF/classes` in case of war packaging and for `beans.xml` it is not correct location. From the other hand `webapp` is a root for web application files, like htmls, jsps, images, etc. and is also used to store any descriptors in the `WEB-INF` subfolder (like web.xml) and other config files which should be placed in `WEB-INF` after packaging.